# SetInterval keeps calling same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have this function:

```
original = 0;
original = original+1;
setInterval("dis"+original+"();", 2400);
```

But there is a problem, every time it is called it appears to be calling the same function over again... They're not calling individual functions.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JosiahHester That does not fix the issue. The issue is that `setInterval` binds the current value of `original` and calls that ever time 2400ms passes. You just bound the value of `original` as well, but incremented it to `original+1` after your `setInterval` call, so the result is exactly the same.

Comment: I feel really bad for myself, dumbest question ever asked. :P Anyways thanks a heap, I should have seen that.

Comment: This seems like a rather strange pattern.  What do all these `dis1`, `dis2`, etc. functions do and is there an unlimited number of them?  Having one function called `dis` and passing the changing value of `original` to it would seem to make more sense but I don't totally know your use case.

Comment: true, I should have probably done it hat way :P @go-oleg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to regenerate the function name every time as setInterval doesn't take care of that for you - it always runs the code that was passed to it when it was set up.

This will find the correct function in global scope (`window`) and call it:

```
original = 0;
original = original+1;
setInterval(function(){
    window["dis" + original]();
    original++;
}, 2400);
```

Incrementing the counter also needs to be done in the setInterval handler.

Comment: I feel really bad for myself, dumbest question ever asked. :P Anyways thanks a heap, I should have seen that.

Comment: But your answer doesn't work in this case :\ What's wrong?  http://dumbsearch.com/towerdef.php

Comment: I think the problem is that it tries to call `dis0` but your functions are numbered from `dis1`. So add a `dis0` function or do `original = 1`.

Comment: dang, that was easy. fixed it, by putting original++ at the beggining of the setinterval :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the fact that `original` is used to construct the callback function name once - and only once - to call `setInterval`. As the name suggests, `setInterval` sets a callback once and continues executing until you clear the interval with `clearInterval`.

If you like to change the method beeing called, you could try `setTimeout`, i.e.:

```
var original = 0,
    cb = function() {
        ('dis' + original).prototype.call(null);
        original++;
        setTimeout(cb, 2400);
    }
cb();
```

Comment: Different approach. Like that.

Comment: I heard before that they were more controllable, cool how it is used like a loop :)

Comment: BUT it doesn't work, both @matt's answer and yours :\ http://dumbsearch.com/towerdef.php

Comment: sry. the question would be how to get the desired functions -- one could use eval (for instance http://jsfiddle.net/NFw94/).
however, some consider it evil. so you could stash your functions in an object and reference this object like @Matt in his answer with the window object.

Comment: you need to set your functions on an object explicitly: i.e. window['dis0'] = function() { //do stuff } and call it like so: window['dis0'](). Hint: read about scopes in javascript, this really helped me to understand a lot" https://www.google.de/search?q=scopes+in+javascript